# Retrofit request url prevent urlencode android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, urlencode

I have a retrofit request

```
@GET("{link}")
suspend fun getFilePart(@Path(value = "link") link: String): Deferred<NetworkResponse<ResponseBody, NetworkError>>
```

and when i call it i pass a 'link'

```
val base = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) BuildConfig.TRANSFER_URL_DEBUG else BuildConfig.TRANSFER_URL
apiManager.appApiService(base).getFilePart(it.link)
```

Lets say the link is something like "https://storage_dev.example.com/10002/6d197e1e57e37070760c4ae28bf1..." but in the Logcat i see that some characters get urlEncoded.
For example

the following Url
https://storage_dev.example.com/10002/6d197e1e57e37070760c4ae28bf18d813abd35a372b6a1f462e4cef21e505860.1&Somethingelse

turns to
https://storage_dev.example.com/10002/6d197e1e57e37070760c4ae28bf18d813abd35a372b6a1f462e4cef21e505860.1%3FSomethingelse

As i can see the link is a String that has many characters inside that get encoded like "&" has turned to "%3F"

How can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `encoded = true` to your request param to tell retrofit to not encode it again:

```
/**
 * Specifies whether the parameter {@linkplain #value() name} and value are already URL encoded.
 */
boolean encoded() default false;
```

Example:

```
@Path(value = "link", encoded = true)
```

Comment: I have tried that but does not seem to work. I have edited the post

Answer (score 0):

If your link includes the baseurl part you should use @Url to avoid that problem

```
@GET
suspend fun getFilePart(@Url link: String): Deferred<NetworkResponse<ResponseBody, NetworkError>>
```

Comment: No...the baseUrl is a parameter to the Contructor. However i didn't know that!!

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm late but however this is how I solved it ..

my issue was the url to containes `"` so on request url it gets encoded then  looks like this `domain.com/api/%22SOME_URL_%22` 
simply just add interceptor to catch the request and decode it.

```
 if(it.request().url().toString().contains("api/MY_SUB_DOMAIN")){
  
val newUrl = java.net.URLDecoder.decode( it.request().url().toString(),
 StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())      //  <--- This is your main solution (decode)

.replace("\"", "")                   // <---- I had to do this to remove parenthasis "


 requestBuilder.url(newUrl)          // <--- DONT FORGET TO ASSAIGN THE NEW URL
            

}
```